# AJAX request fails with internal server error in Sinatra app

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm creating a game in which a user's guess is sent to backend, where it is evaluated and then feedback in the form of an array is returned. I'm using AJAX to retrieve an array of data from a Sinatra back end.  Here is the relevant call from my javascript file:

```js
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // i've tried with and without this line
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/guess",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 
            guessData: choices, 
            secret: sessionStorage.getItem('secretcode')
        },  
        success: function(result) { 
            var response = JSON.parse(result);
            var html = "<span>" + response + "</span>";
            $('#response').append(html);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
        }
    })
});
```

Here is my Ruby code that returns the array:

```
post '/guess' do
    response = Guess.new(params)
    @response = response.feedback.to_json
end
```

Using Pry I've confirmed that the `@response` variable is `'[0,2]'`.  I've entered this in JSONLint, which says that it is valid JSON. However, the response always goes the error route in the jQuery AJAX call and I get this error:

[status 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEj9d.png)

I've tried to implement the suggestions offered in other Stack Overflow questions with a similar issue but nothing seems to work.

Here is my log.  It does not change during or after the AJAX request.  All four entries occurred before the AJAX request.

[server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c196o.png)

Comment: A 5xx error code means the error is happening on your server. You need to debug there, not the JS

Comment: what is your response from server?

Comment: How about your server log? What does it say?

Comment: I added the server log.  @Rory McCrossan I'm not sure what more to do on the server.  I've tried to return a simple string, array, hash and an integer but they all result in the same error.  The AJAX request is definitely being directed to the correct route but when it returns something is happening. Thanks all!

Comment: Change the POST to a GET and then just load the url directly, it should show a stacktrace with some more informationa about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed to change the instance variable @response to a regular variable.  The use of an instance variable to return the data must have caused an issue in the view because erb template uses instance variables for specific purposes.

```
  response = Guess.new(params)
  final_response = response.feedback.to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it: Error is sending `data`:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/guess",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {'guessData': choices, 'secret': sessionStorage.getItem('secretcode')},  
      success: function(result){
        var response = JSON.parse(result);
        var html = "<span>" + response + "</span>";
        $('#response').append(html);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(jqXHR.responseText)
      }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but that wasn't it.  In debugging the code, it appears to be sending the POST data just fine.  The processing of the data seems to return the expected value but then for some reason in returning the response to the javascript I get a 500 error.